# How to create a bounding box around objects selected by ismember?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

By following this post [Using ismember with the output of regionprops](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/27/using-ismember-with-the-output-of-regionprops/) I am able to selectively isolate the connected component I want. For example using my code below:

```
img = rgb2gray(imread('W1\Writer1_01_02.jpg'));
bw_normal2 = im2bw(img, graythresh(img));
bw22 = imcomplement(bw_normal2);
bw3 = bwmorph(bw22, 'dilate');
[label2,n2] = bwlabel(bw3);
stats2 = regionprops(label2, {'Area', 'BoundingBox'});
area2 = [stats2.Area];

idx = find((28 <= area2) & (area2 <= 40));
   BW2 = ismember(label2,idx);
figure, imshow(BW2)
```

I can easily display the output that contains ONLY the connected component whose area is between 28 and 40. As so

[image]

But instead can I make a bounding box around this connected component in the original image. I mean if this is the original image:
[image]

Can I make a bounding box around my desired component on the original image? I know that this is the code for making a bounding box around all of my connected components

```
imshow(img);
for j=1:n2

    hold on
    rectangle('Position',[stats(j).BoundingBox(1),stats(j).BoundingBox(2),stats(j).BoundingBox(3),stats(j).BoundingBox(4)],...
'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 );
end
```

But how do I only make a bounding box only around the element having area between 28 and 40? Rather than producing a completely different image as shown above.

Comment: I might not have understood the question properly. But it seems like that you have the following piece of code `for j=1:n2` which would mean that you are traversing each of the component on the image. Find the number which represents the object of interest and draw the bounding box.

Comment: That would be quite difficult and time consuming. Say I only want the object having an area of 40. I would then open the ``stats2.Area `` in my workspace, find it and then apply it to my code. I just added that second code to show that I know how to draw a bounding box around all components but how to draw on the original image for the element selected by ``ismember``?

Comment: Er, what's difficult about `stats2(idx).BoundingBox`? If you're not clear _how_ the code works, try stepping through in the debugger to see what the values are, and how they change, line-by-line (use "step over" rather than "step into" to avoid the guts of all the functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a if condition in your second half of the code...

```
imshow(img);
for j=1:n2
 hold on
 area2 = stats2(j).Area;
 if((28 <= area2) & (area2 <= 40))
  rectangle('Position',[stats2(j).BoundingBox(1),stats2(j).BoundingBox(2),stats2(j).BoundingBox(3),stats2(j).BoundingBox(4)],...'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2 );
 end
end
```